# Postgres query to make faster

Tags: postgresql

Any opinion on which query will be faster ( or no difference) and why?

```
select * from A a left join B b on a.id = b.cid where b.cl1 = 's1' or b.c1 ='s2' or b.c1 ='s3' ;
```

or

```
select * from A a left join B b  on a.id = b.cid where b.cl1 in ('s1','s2','s3');
```

The above is just examples to provide idea on what I am trying to do. May not be the exact syntax.

The reason for asking the question is , I built up a spring-hibernate-JPA query similar to the first one and at this point performance is poor. Hence looking for all possible ways to make the performance better. It may or may not be the query. But not being expert on DB side, looking for information

Comment: Why do you need opinions on this? Why not run a benchmark?

Comment: Generate the explain plans for each and you'll likely find that they're identical. There is no need for an opinion. Also, opinion based questions are against SO policy and get closed. *(Other than the syntax errors; you should have `ON` instead of `WHERE`)*

Comment: `select * from A a left join (select * from B b where b.cl1 = 's1' or b.c2 ='s2' or b.c3 ='s3');` should be faster by pushing down the selection to pre join

Comment: Wait, they're different. One checks `cl1`, `c2` and `c3`, the other only checks `cl1`. They're not comparable.

Comment: Please share more details - if you are facing performance problems, why not run analyze the execution plan to see whether indices are missing?

Comment: Here is a radical idea. You have already written both queries. Why not just run them both and test test them.

Answer (score 1):

In such scenarios, you can simply analyze your query by using [PostgreSQL query analize](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-analyze.html) and see which one is speed.

> Update: As @MatBailie said on his comment, LEFT JOIN requires an ON
> clause.

```
EXPLAIN ANALYSE
SELECT *
FROM A a
         LEFT JOIN B ON b
WHERE b.cl1 = 's1'
   OR b.c2 = 's2'
   OR b.c3 = 's3';

EXPLAIN ANALYSE
SELECT *
FROM A a
         LEFT JOIN B ON b
WHERE b.cl1 IN ('s1', 's2', 's3');
```

Comment: Analize means something very different.

Comment: You also copied the Op's syntax errors. `LEFT JOIN` requires an `ON` clause.

Comment: @MatBailie Oops, just saw that :)

Answer (score 1):

The second query is always faster, because it can use a single index scan if you have an index on `b.cl1`.

But since the first query has the conditions on different columns, the queries are quite different, and it makes little sense to compare them.